# Why is add button causing a crash?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

What I'm trying to do is have a button that will pull the information from UIPickerviewer that will then add that to an array but when the program runs and you hit the button it crashes. Quite new to programming in swift... Would like a better explanation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var PickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var list: [UILabel]!

    @IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var shift = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    var deviceList = [""]
    var shift = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = "Device List"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let devices = ["Mobile Phone","Microwave","Heater","Fridge","Router","Drill"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1            
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return devices[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return devices.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        label.text = devices[row]
        if(shift == true){
            deviceList.append(label.text!)
            print(deviceList)
            shift = false
        }        
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please show us the error text / output of the console

Comment: Give us the full error message you're getting and tell us what line it crashes on. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You have an invalid redeclaration of variable **shift**, you have declared it in both the main class and in the uibutton function. Move **var shift = false** before the @IBAction and delete the keyword **var** in your function's body

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[hod.ViewController buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffcebc02e30'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a crash when you tap on your button I assume there is some conflicting assignments with the `IBOutlet` events referencing. The reason being is because your `add(_:)` action method isn't doing anything but creating a new boolean property called `shift`, and even though it's the same name as the class property `shift` (`self.shift`), that actually shouldn't cause a crash. Sometimes in interface builder you can have an outlet that you accidentally assigned more than one event, and that has usually caused a crash in my experience if you deleted one of the events in your code. For example: say you created a event for your button (like `add(_:)`), and then forgot and accidentally created a second one. You then realized your mistake and deleted the code for the second event, but didn't know you had to remove the event outlet. Interface builder will allow you to make this mistake, but will cause the app to crash when you tap the button, because it's trying to call an event that doesn't exist anymore.

If you want to check if you have any unnecessary event assignments through IB, control+click on the button in your documents outline on the left side of the screen using Interface Builder.

[image]

You'll see the referencing outlets listed under the "Referencing Outlets" header. You can remove any unnecessary ones by clicking the little "X" to the top left. You can also tell if the outlet is actually connected, by checking if it has a little filled circle to the right (this means it's connected).  Here is an example, in this case I created an event call to a method called `tryAgain:` which I then removed. It causes a crash when I tap the button.

[image]

If I click the "X" button and remove the `tryAgain:` event. The app will work when the button is clicked.

I'm not certain this is your issue, but based on what you've shared it sounds likely to me. Hope this helps. I would recommend actually executing some code in your `add(_:)` method, however.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the IBAction you posted should be causing a crash. You do need to get rid of the word "var" in the body of the function so that it changes the state of your instance variable rather than setting a local variable that never does anything, but that won't cause a crash.

That said, your "label" outlet is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional, which is normal for outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

If the outlet is not connected to anything, though, then any time you try to read from or write to the label outlet or a property of the label, you'll crash if label is nil.

Check to see if you outlet is hooked up correctly. If it's not, then I would expect you to crash when you operate your picker. (Not when you click the add button.)